# Multilingual file management for C# and PHP

Tags: php, multilingual, resx

I have a large inhouse system written in a combination of C# and PHP. I'm about to try to make it multilingual.

Based on my research so far it looks like the best way to make this work is by using **resx** files on the C# side and **.po/.mo** files in PHP. There will be a lot of duplication between these files as the same phrases will be needed for both sides of the code.

What I am wondering is are there any automated tools in existance that can help me manage/generate this data once the initial translations have been figured out?

**Specifically I am looking for some sort of translation management tool that is capable of generating both .resx and .po/.mo file outputs so that these files can easily be kept in sync with one another.**

Any suggestions greatly appreciated. 
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Personally, I use JSON files, might not be the best way, but I have a custom class in PHP to handle those and in C# it wouldn't be hard to implement. I find resx a bit complicated with C# for desktop applications. (but not in ASP.NET)

Comment: Hi jValdron. Thank you for your response but I am specifically looking for a pre-existing tool. I know I can build something custom if I need to. I'd just prefer to use an existing tool if possible.

Comment: Its a bit late but just adding this little piece to the discussion. Basically, why use two files when you can achieve with one(.po)? There are various implementations of PO files to c# are available, like [FairlyLocal](http://www.fairtutor.com/fairlylocal/fairlylocal-overview) or [gettext-cs-utils](http://code.google.com/p/gettext-cs-utils/). FairlyLocal looks promising among these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bingo. [ResourceBlender](http://www.resourceblender.com/) can import and export to and from **both** po and resx files. Awesome. Extra plus; it is open source. (I'm not affiliated with this product)

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to find a plugin to provide translation management specifically for the resx files. It is supplied by this company http://www.hexadigm.com/. (I have no affiliation with this company) It plugs directly into Visual Studio. Looks like it may solve **some** of my problems.

Sadly it does not have anything to handle the po/mo side of things. I'm thinking I could use this tool to forward the strings to our translation company and keep the C# side of things in check. Then build a separate script to generate the po files based on the contents of the resx files.

There has got to be a neater way of doing this? Thinking I'll have to build a completely custom solution.

Comment: You can build a wrapper around .resx in PHP using SimpleXML, as .resx files are just some "fancy" XMLs.

Answer (score 0):

try to have also a look at Microsoft MAT. This will also give you industry standard xlf files: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MultilingualAppToolkit.MultilingualAppToolkit-18308